# Not complete connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, semi-riemannian-geometry

In my lecture, it says that for each open $U \subset M$ the induced connection $\nabla^U$ on $TU$ is not complete.

Here $M$ is a smooth manifold and $\nabla$ is a connection on $TM$.

Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: What do you mean by a "complete connection"?

Comment: A connection s.t. the maximal geodesics are defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: If this was true then it would imply complete connections don't exist (take $U=M$). Have you missed some other assumption about $U$?

Comment: We assume that $U \neq M$

Comment: Think about geodesics passing through a boundary point of $U$.